# Зациклилась программа на асм 86

Tags: ассемблер

Есть простенькая программа на ASM x86. Должна запрашивать символьный ряд, считать количество символов "*" в этом ряду и выводить это количество на экран.

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 200h
.DATA
String DB 255, ?, 255 dup (?), '$'
N DB ?
Nstr DB 4 dup (?), '$'
Zv db '*', '$'
Nost DB ?
.CODE
ProgramStart:   mov ax, @DATA
                mov ds, ax

            mov ah, 0ah
            mov dx, offset String
            int 21h

            xor cx, cx
            mov cl, String[1]
            xor ax, ax
            mov si, 2
            mov bh, Zv

            jcxz ProgramStart
Cycle1:         mov dl, String[si]
                cmp dl, bh
                jne jump1
                jmp jump2

Jump1:          inc si  
                loop Cycle1

Jump2:          inc si
                inc al
                loop Cycle1


            mov N, al

            xor cl, cl
            mov bh, 10
            xor dl, dl

Cycle2:         inc cl
                div bh
                cmp al, dl
                jne Cycle2

            xor ax, ax
            mov al, N
            mov Nost, al

            xor si, si
            mov si, offset Nstr
            add si, ax
            mov byte ptr[si], '$'

Cycle3:         dec si
                div bh
                add [si], ah
                add byte ptr[si], '0'
                xor ah, ah
                mov al, Nost
                div bh
                mov Nost, al
                cmp al, dl
                jne Cycle3


            mov ah, 09h
            mov dx, offset Nstr
            int 21h

            xor ah, ah
            int 16h
            mov ah, 4Ch
            int 21h

END ProgramStart
```

Программа работает некорректно. После ввода символьного ряда, на экран начинают беспорядочно выводиться символы. Объясните мне, пожалуйста, где я ошибаюсь. Используемый компилятор: тасм.

Comment: Отладчик-то вы почему не используете?

Comment: Теперь использую)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьми за привычку писать хоть какие нибудь комментарии, в ассемблере это очень важно.
Итак:
Если я правильно понял, в `N` у тебя кол-во звездочек. далее ты считаешь кол-во десятичных разрядов в числе звездочек

```
Cycle2:  inc cl
         div bh
         cmp al, dl
         jne Cycle2
```

По окончании цикла кол-во разрядов в `CL`
Но `CL` далее в программе нигде не используется !!!
В итоге ты в выводимую строку пишешь '$' не в ее конец, а по смещению AX, где в этот момент у тебя полное кол-во звездочек. Это плюс ко всему за пределами объявленной под него области памяти.
Вот в этом месте:

```
mov si, offset Nstr
add si, ax
mov byte ptr[si], '$'
```

Ты видимо хотел написать

```
mov si, offset Nstr
xor ch,ch
add si, cx
mov byte ptr[si], '$'
```

P.S. Ну и подсчет кол-ва звездочек у тебя явно не оптимален, гораздо короче вот так:

```
Cycle1: mov dl, String[si]
        cmp dl, bh
        jne jump1     
        inc al
Jump1:  inc si
        loop Cycle1
```

Да, на будущее запомни, если при использовании 9 функции int 21h у тебя бегут символы, значит $ стоит не там или отсутствует, ну или в прерывание передан неправильный указатель на строку :)